# Why can't add file handler with the form of self.fh in the init method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

os and python info:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
python3 --version
Python 3.9.2
```

Here is a simple class which can start multiprocessing.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool    

class my_mp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.process_num = 3
        fh = open('test.txt', 'w')
    def run_task(self,i):
        print('process {} start'.format(str(i)))
        time.sleep(2)
        print('process {} end'.format(str(i)))
    def run(self):
        pool = Pool(processes = self.process_num)
        for i in range(self.process_num):
            pool.apply_async(self.run_task,args = (i,))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Initialize the `my_mp` class,then start multiprocess.

```
ins = my_mp()
ins.run()
process 0 start
process 1 start
process 2 start
process 0 end
process 2 end
process 1 end
```

Now replace `fh = open('test.txt', 'w')` with `self.fh = open('test.txt', 'w')` in `my_mp` class and try again.

```
ins = my_mp()
ins.run()
```

No output!Why no process start?

```
>>> from multiprocessing.pool import Pool    
>>> 
>>> class my_mp(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.process_num = 3
...         fh = open('test.txt', 'w')
...     def run_task(self,i):
...         print('process {} start'.format(str(i)))
...         time.sleep(2)
...         print('process {} end'.format(str(i)))
...     def run(self):
...         pool = Pool(processes = self.process_num)
...         for i in range(self.process_num):
...             pool.apply_async(self.run_task,args = (i,))
...         pool.close()
...         pool.join()
... 
>>> x = my_mp()
>>> x.run()
process 0 start
process 1 start
process 2 start
process 2 end
process 0 end
process 1 end
>>> class my_mp(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.process_num = 3
...         self.fh = open('test.txt', 'w')
...     def run_task(self,i):
...         print('process {} start'.format(str(i)))
...         time.sleep(2)
...         print('process {} end'.format(str(i)))
...     def run(self):
...         pool = Pool(processes = self.process_num)
...         for i in range(self.process_num):
...             pool.apply_async(self.run_task,args = (i,))
...         pool.close()
...         pool.join()
... 
>>> x = my_mp()
>>> x.run()
>>> x.run()
>>> x = my_mp()
>>> class my_mp(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.process_num = 3
...         fh = open('test.txt', 'w')
...         self.fh = fh
...     def run_task(self,i):
...         print('process {} start'.format(str(i)))
...         time.sleep(2)
...         print('process {} end'.format(str(i)))
...     def run(self):
...         pool = Pool(processes = self.process_num)
...         for i in range(self.process_num):
...             pool.apply_async(self.run_task,args = (i,))
...         pool.close()
...         pool.join()
... 
>>> x = my_mp()
>>> x.run()
>>>
```

Why can't add file handler with the form of `self.fh` in the `__init__` method?I have never called the file handler defined in `__init__` in any process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The problem:

Stdlib multiprocessing uses [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to serialize objects. Anything which needs to be sent across the process boundary needs to be picklable.

Custom class instances are generally picklable, as long as all their attributes are picklable - it works by importing the type within the subprocess and unpickling the attributes.

The issue is that the object returned by `open()` is not picklable.

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps(A())
b'\x80\x04\x95\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x01A\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94.'
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.fh = open("test.txt", "w")
... 
>>> pickle.dumps(A())
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

In the first case, the multiprocessing pool still works because `fh` is just a local variable and it's deleted as soon as it's out of scope, i.e. when the `__init__` method returns. But as soon as you save this handle into the instance's namespace with `self.fh = open(...)`, there will remain a reference and it will need to be sent over the process boundary.

You might think that since you've only scheduled the method `self.run_task` to execute in the pool, that the state set from `__init__` doesn't matter, but that's not the case. There is still a reference:

```
>>> ins = my_mp()
>>> ins.run_task.__self__.__dict__
{'process_num': 3,
 'fh': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>}
```

Note that calling `ins = my_mp()` runs the `__init__` method in the main process, and `ins.run_task` is the object which gets sent over the process boundary.

#### Solution:

There is a third-party library which provides a drop-in replacement for the stdlib multiprocessing Pool - `pip install pathos` and replace the multiprocessing import with:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import Pool
```

[pathos](https://pypi.org/project/pathos/) uses [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/), a more powerful serialization library than pickle, so it is able to serialize the objects returned by `open()`. Your code should work again without any other changes. However, you should beware that each worker process will not know about other processes writing bytes to `self.fh`, so whichever worker writes last may overwrite data written earlier from some other process.

Answer (score 2):

I did some investigation, but it does not fully answer the question. I am going to post the results here in case if they help somebody else.

First, if the subprocess fails, there is no traceback. So I added the additional line to display the output of subprocesses. It should be `None` if no errors occur. The new code:

```py
        for i in range(3):
            res = pool.apply_async(self.run_task, args=(i,))
            print(res.get())
```

The output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/temp/LeetCode-solutions/multithreading.py", line 43, in <module>
    mp.run()
  File "C:/temp/LeetCode-solutions/multithreading.py", line 19, in run
    self.multiprocessing()
  File "C:/temp/LeetCode-solutions/multithreading.py", line 30, in multiprocessing
    print(res.get())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 537, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

It seems that the program gets the file object as part of the argument to `self.run_task`. The error has a long history on StackOverflow, but the best explanation IMO is here:
https://discuss.python.org/t/use-multiprocessing-module-to-handle-a-large-file-in-python/6604

I didn't find why having an attribute that is file object makes all the attributes of the class file objects, but I hope that unveils some mystery.

Final test: the following code works as expected

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import time


class MyMP(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.process_num = 3

    def run(self):
        self.fh = open('test.txt', 'w')
        pool = Pool(processes=3)
        for i in range(3):
            res = pool.apply_async(run_task, args=(i,))
            print(res.get())
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        self.fh.close()

def run_task(i):
    print('process {} start'.format(str(i)))
    time.sleep(2)
    print('process {} end'.format(str(i)))
```